# Solarium - curl error - using solr under php 7

Tags: curl, solr, centos, php-7, solarium

I am using Solr 5.4, with its user interface working perfectly.

I've installed [Solarium](http://www.solarium-project.org/) to help with the development of my user interface. Although, I am receiving this error when trying to use the example codes:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught Solarium\Exception\HttpException: Solr HTTP 
 error: HTTP request failed, Connection timed out after 5001 milliseconds in solarium/library/Solarium/Core/Client/Adapter/Curl.php:195 Stack trace: #0
 solarium/library/Solarium/Core/Client/Adapter/Curl.php(92): Solarium\Core\Client\Adapter\Curl->check('', Array, Resource id #37) #1 
 solarium/library/Solarium/Core/Client/Adapter/Curl.php(213): Solarium\Core\Client\Adapter\Curl->getResponse(Resource id #37, false) #2 
 solarium/library/Solarium/Core/Client/Adapter/Curl.php(68): Solarium\Core\Client\Adapter\Curl->getData(Object(Solarium\Core\Client\Request), Object(Solarium\Core\Client\Endpoint)) #3 
 solarium/library/Solarium/Core/Client/Client.php(804): Solarium\Core\Client\Adapter\Curl->execute(Object(Solarium\Core\Client\Request), Object(Solariu in solarium/library/Solarium/Core/Client/Adapter/Curl.php on line 195
```

I am under a CentOS server running php7, with php70w-common installed, which comes with php-curl as indicated in [webtatic.com](https://webtatic.com/packages/php70/). Curl and Libcurl already installed as well.

Has anyone faced this same issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Quick question, why Solr 3.4? Why not 5.x or something newer like at least 4.10?

Comment: Sorry @xmorera it´s 5.4.

Comment: Same issue here